# C# SQL поиск по таблице

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Не могу понять, в чем проблема, где-то накосячила с запросом, но не могу понять, где...

```
  public void Search()
    {
            Boolean z = false;
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM goods WHERE ";
            if (tb_Name.Text != "")
            {
                sql = sql + "name =" + tb_Name.Text;
                z = true;

            }

            if (tb_Count.Text != "")
            {

                if (z)
                {
                    sql = sql + " and  ";
                }
                sql = sql + "count =" + "'" + tb_Count.Text + "'";
                z = true;
            }
            if (tb_Cost.Text != "")
            {

                if (z)
                {
                    sql = sql + " and  ";
                }
                sql = sql + "cost =" + "'" + tb_Cost.Text + "'";
                z = true;
            }

            if (z) { } else { sql = "Select * from goods"; }


            connect.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connect);
            SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            DataTable DATA = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(DATA);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DATA;
        }
        catch (SqlException a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }

        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
        View();                           
    }
```

Думаю косяк где-то тут:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM goods WHERE ";
            if (tb_Name.Text != "")
            {
                sql = sql + "name =" + tb_Name.Text;
                z = true;

            }

            if (tb_Count.Text != "")
            {

                if (z)
                {
                    sql = sql + " and  ";
                }
                sql = sql + "count =" + "'" + tb_Count.Text + "'";
                z = true;
            }
            if (tb_Cost.Text != "")
            {

                if (z)
                {
                    sql = sql + " and  ";
                }
                sql = sql + "cost =" + "'" + tb_Cost.Text + "'";
                z = true;
            }

            if (z) { } else { sql = "Select * from goods"; }
```

Явных ошибок не выдаёт, ничего просто не происходит. В этом фрагменте кода я уверена, работает в другом методе:

```
        connect.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connect);
        SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        DataTable DATA = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(DATA);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DATA;
```

Comment: Использую sql server

Comment: Не вдаваясь в подробности кода, просто начните с использования параметризации запроса вместо конкатенации строк [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Соберите  запрос примерно так  var  sql = $” SELECT * FROM goods WHERE {name} and {count} “ не используя конкатенацию строк и посмотрите что внутри, если запрос рабочий, то он просто выдаёт Вам пустые значения, напишите  запрос напрямую к базе...

Answer (score -1):

Воспроизведите ситуацию, когда у вас ничего не происходит, но изначально точку остановы поставьте перед окончанием метода и посмотрите какой запрос лежит в вашей переменной sql. Далее проверьте запрос через sqlmanager ведя запрос из вашей переменной. После запроса, сразу увидите в какую сторону копать. Если sql, смотрите синтаксис, а если проблема в коде, то проверяйте подключение.

Comment: это больше комментарий, чем ответ

Comment: @tym32167 было бы больше репутации, оставил комментарий. Однако пришлось писать ответ, дабы хоть как то ускорить решение проблемы человека.

Comment: Ответы определенно не для этого существуют - ответ должен быть ответом, комментарий - комментарием.